# Get Firebase Entity Key upon its creation in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

When creating a new entity in Firebase with the following test code:

```
class Person{
 String name;
 int age;
 Person({this.name, this.age});
}

Person person = new Person(name: 'John', age: '42');

.
.
.

aMethod async() {
 Firestore _firestore = Firestore.instance;
 var firestoreResult = await _firestore.collection('Example').add({
  'name': person.name,
  'age': person.age
 });
}
```

I want to retrieve its key from the firebase.

I saw in debugging mode that the **firestoreResult** returns the wanted key within its parameters like this:

```
firestoreResult._delegate._pathComponents[1]
```

The problem is that its parameters are private and thus I am getting the following error:

```
The getter _delegate is not defined for the class DocumentReference
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the document id try the following:

```
 var firestoreResult = await _firestore.collection('Example').add({
  'name': person.name,
  'age': person.age
 });
var documentId = firestoreResult.documentID;
```

The `add()` method returns a `Future` of type `DocumentReference` and inside the class `DocumentReference` you can use the property `documentID` to get the id:

https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore/lib/src/document_reference.dart#L39

Answer (score 1):

var documentID = firestoreResult.documentID;